# Current file name format is "Number1_1170_Date" and I want those files to be renamed as "Number2_1170_Date". But Number2 is a column in SQL database?

Tags: vba, excel

As of now I have multiple folder file names that are in format of

```
"Number1_1170_Date"
```

and I am trying to change the format into

```
"Number2_1170_Date"
```

But the issue here is: `Number2` is a column in SQL database which has to be compared with `Number1` in the file name, and then replaced accordingly. **How can i achieve this?**

I have a VBA script for picking all filenames in a folder,editing out the extra file name and get only `"Number1"`, but I will need further VBA code that can relate the `Number1` with `Number2` in `SQL` AND then produce the `number2` in a format of

`"number2_1170_date"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function ChangeName(oldfilename as string, conn as ado.connection) as string
dim oldnumber as long
oldnumber =clng(left(oldfilename,instr(oldfilename,"_")-1))
dim rs as new recordset
rs.open "select number2 from mytable where number1 = " & oldnumber,conn
if not rs.eof then
     changename = replace(oldfilename,oldnumber,rs(0))
else
     changename = oldfilename
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing
end function
```

You will need a reference to Microsoft Activex Dataobjects and you'll need to create an appropriate connection object to your database

Comment: Great ! So is this code gonna refer "number1" in the excel while selecting number2 from mytable ? Because I see that in the where clause ("....where number1 =  ") nothing is being referred to number1 column in mytable, which in this case has to refer to number1 in the excel sheet, before displaying appropriate number2 accordingly. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: the function takes everything before the _ character in the old file name as the old number ie "Number1". If you want to pass it the old number directly just edit the argument to use oldnumber instead of oldfilename, delete the first two rows and edit the changename = replace... line to just read changename = rs(0)

Comment: Great !. If you don't mind, can you let me know how the structure of sub xxxx () .......end sub() should be for this function ? Thank you so much.

Comment: I am new to VBA, so please let me know how the sub xxx() ...end sub () structure should be for the above VBA function. Thanks